# neo4j basic hello-world code throws UnsupportedClassVersionError error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, neo4j

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/neo4j/graphdb/RelationshipType : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

Now I know from here : [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0) that neo4j might be needing a different version of JRE so compile time jre and runtime jre are a mismatch. I tried to change them through project specific settings but none of them worked. I am using 2.0.0 milestone release neo4j-community jars.

Let me know what other information I should provide.

Comment: Basically you need to run with Java 7. You haven't told us anything about how you're trying to run it at the moment.

Comment: This is the code I am trying to run https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0-M04/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using the above code, and adding the community jars on the build path as a user-library and compiler compliance in eclipse is set to 6.0

Comment: Neo4J 2.0* only supports Java 7 from now on.

Answer (score 3):

Worked with updating to java-7-openjdk. Thanks @jon-skeet